# Seeking for penmanship advice

Tags: discussion

Before criticizing my post being in the wrong section or whatsoever, I want to say: within my knowledge, I judged this to be the most reliable platform for this question.

If I am banned from the forum, or you must move my question or close it, please answer my question to the best of your ability before doing so. I want to learn English.

Is there anyone who can provide a website/link or an explicit set of instructions on how to improve penmanship?

Comment: What sort of writing do you want to do?

Comment: Something like [The Palmer Method](http://palmermethod.com/)?

Comment: Or a [*fine Italian hand*](http://www.fountainpennetwork.com/forum/index.php/topic/2035-chancery-italic-script-instructions/)?

Comment: Handwriting -- of any sort -- is a personal matter, rather like one's voice, which can be recognized and understood easily. The main thing is **practice** (or, alternatively, good typing ability and an **extremely** good set of fonts). Like any drawing skill, it's a matter of training hand and eye together. Find the letters (52 of them, at least) that you prefer to be **your** versions, and practice them all until you are satisfied with the results in any combination. There is ample room for creativity and legibility.

Comment: If you want to *learn* English, you might enjoy the help of [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).  English Language & Usage (this site) is not so focused on helping learners.

Comment: the Graphics Design.SE site has a [question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/16997) on resources for learning calligraphy which may be of value. You might explore that site to see whether it would accept the question. And [this question](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/66/would-improving-my-penmanship-improve-my-productivity) on the Personal Productivity site has some suggestions.

Comment: Stoney, thanks very much for your reply. I read the two links you provided - the graphic design and personal productivity site - and I'm more clear knowing what I really want. I want to write legibly so everyone can read my writing. I'll start with kid's writing http://www.softschools.com/handwriting/alphabets/letter_b_worksheets/letter_b_worksheet_3_1_trace.pdf    I am disgusted by my writing at times so thanks for everyone's inputs. Like to hear more elementary writing improvement suggestions.